# Passing Python Social Auth username into View

Tags: python, django

Users can log in with Facebook using Python Social Auth

I have confirmed that the Facebook data is obtainable by using this in one of my templates

```
{% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}
   <p class="navbar-text"><a href="/recommendations/{{user.username}}">{{ user.username }}!</a></p>
   <p class="navbar-text"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></p>
{% else %}
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in with Facebook</button></a>
{% endif %}
```

but when I try to call user.username within a view such as below, it is returning an error.

```
def personalised(user):
    return HttpResponse(user.username)
```

Error:

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'username'
```

I believe this is coming from my `urls.py` setup

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url,include
from soundshelterapp import views

```
urlpatterns = patterns('soundshelterapp.views',
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^personalised$', views.personalised, name='name'),
    url(r'^social/', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^login/$', 'login',name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'logout',name='logout')
    )
```

Comment: isn't that be `user.username` instead of `user.user_name`?

Comment: @Anzel yep good spot, have updated the question (still same error)

Comment: if that's a **request** object, it should be `user.user.username` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing context variables and Django views. `personalised` is a Django view and its argument is a `request` object and not `user` which you are doing.

The `{{user}}` you are getting in your template is because of [`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) which adds `user` variable in the context representing the currently logged-in user. Since the user is loggedin, `request.user` attribute will be set to the logged-in user and then you can access the `username` using `request.user.username`.

```
def personalised(request): # request object is passed to a view
    username = request.user.username # get the username of logged-in user
    return HttpResponse(username) # return response
```

Comment: Change the argument of your view to contain `request` instead of `user`.

Comment: Works perfectly and thank you for the explanation on the django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth - awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I have used like to get usernme

```
def personalised(request):
    current_user = request.user
```